# How to set default graphics card Windows 10 desktop. GTX 960 and GT 1030

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu, gaming

I am having trouble with a few things regarding my current setup in my gaming PC.

Ever since I've had this computer, it's had a GTX 960 and everything worked perfectly, however trouble arose a few days ago after I added a GT 1030 to my system. I am using the GT 1030 for a small amount of bitcoin mining, it's not like I'm trying to make a huge amount of money, I'm just using my gaming PC to make a small amount to pay for cheap games. At first, I was thinking that everything would work fine, both monitors are plugged in to the GTX 960 and nothing is plugged into the GT 1030.

I first discovered an issue when I attempted to play Minecraft. I've done this many times before and I've seen good FPS, however this time I was getting 20-30 FPS windowed mode and 10-15 FPS fullscreen. I didn't know why this would happen. I'm mining on the 1030, not the 960 and so it shouldn't have an effect on gaming. I pressed F3 in Minecraft to see system information and it said it was using the 1030 for graphics. It shouldn't be doing this and even Nvidia's GPU activity states that javaw.exe (Minecraft) is running with the 960 and not with the 1030. I looked online and found information on using the Manage 3D settings option in the Nvidia control panel to set the preferred graphics processor. I tried this however, I didn't have this option. After googling for a while, I discovered it was only available to gaming laptops and I'm on a desktop.

I decided it wasn't too bad since it's Minecraft and I don't really care about Minecraft, but the true extent of this was made apparent when I attempted to play Pokemon Ultra Moon on Citra, a 3DS emulator. I was getting poor performance (10 FPS) when emulating at 2000x1200 resolution, I did this the a few days ago and got full speed emulation, however 1/3 speed emulation is impossible to use. I didn't want it to be the bitcoin mining, but I disabled it and citra ran at full speed immediately and when re-enabling it, it shot down again.

For Bitcoin mining, I am using Nicehash and have selected only the 1030 to mine. I've used process explorer and process hacker to check the GPU activity and it's the 1030 that's being using 100%, not the 960. I don't have a preferred graphics option in my Nvidia control panel and I'm not going to stop Bitcoin mining since I want a fix to my actual problem instead of a work around.

I've been searching the internet for 3 days seeing if I could find anything, but I couldn't.

All information for "choose default graphics card" or "choose between two graphics cards" or "see which GPU is being used" is giving me information for laptops. I really want to be able to tell all programs to use my 960 while Nicehash mines with the 1030.

I hope I get an answer that will fix my problems,
Thanks

Comment: The reason the info you're finding is for laptops is because laptops are the systems where switchable graphics are an issue, mostly due to power considerations. What you SHOULD be looking at is what changed on your computer a few days ago that precipitated the change.

Answer (score 0):

Since the games are displaying via a cable attached to the "wrong card," (the game is rendering on one GPU and displaying via the other), then this means you have SLI enabled. You don't seem to want that, so you need to disable SLI so that the GPUs act as discreet devices.

I don't use multi-gpu setups but I have heard rumours that sometimes the SLI configuration is missing in the control panel and sometimes swapping slots or uninstalling nvidia drivers and reinstalling will fix that. Note swapping slots may not be desirable depending on the lanes configuration of your PCIe interfaces.

Side note: presuming that bitcoin mining won't impact game performance is not a safe bet. Even minor disk access can cause stuttering that is often worse than simply reduced framerate.

Comment: For googling on your own, try "nvidia disable SLI"